# Change platform toolset for vs2013 by CmakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

I have a VS2013 project with many targets (say a b c d....) in different locations, which is generated by CMake using one top-level CMake and many CMake files in sub directories (using `add_subdirectories`) and now I want to change "Platform Toolset" only for one of the targets (say b) from `v120` to `v90`.

I have tried the following in my CMakeLists.txt for that particular target (say b) but none of them seem to work:

```
set(CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET "v90")
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET "v90")
```

or

```
add_definitions (-DCMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET = "v90")
add_definitions (-DMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET = "v90")
```

or

set_target_properties (b PROPERTIES PLATFORM_TOOLSET "v90")... but doesn't work

Maybe it is possible with command line with -T option but I want to change the toolset for only one target not for the whole project. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: I have also tried : set_target_properties (a PROPERTIES PLATFORM_TOOLSET "v90")... but doesn't work

Comment: Then also mention that in the question.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Problem is I am not able to change "Platform Toolset" for solution in VS2013 by cmake. I tried several options but nothing is working. Please help

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want directly. Although ExternalProject_Add may work. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html

Comment: It is working now !! -  set (CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET "v90"). I used this same command for CmakeLists.txt where I wanted to change the platform toolset. But you need to put this command before project().

Comment: As an example : cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7.0)
set (CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET "v90") #using vs2008 for abc
project (abc)